# Create a Variable from Two Different Variables Using if_else in R

Tags: r, if-statement, variables, dplyr, logical-operators

I am using ACS data to try to create a housing cost burden variable from two different variables, OCPIP and GRPIP.

I want to set those that report 0 as missing and any value greater than 30 as "*Yes*", and any value 1-30 as "*No*". Here is my `dplyr`/`Tidyverse` code:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(cost_burdened = if_else(OCPIP == 0 | GRPIP == 0, NA_character_,
                                 if_else(OCPIP < 31 | GRPIP < 31, "No", "Yes")))
```

I feel like I have it set up right from the way I am reading it which is if X or Y = 0, then they are missing and if X or Y is greater than 31 then they are "*Yes*". If I created two separate variables using the exact `if_else` set up for one of them (so only GRPIP or OCPIP), the code works.

But when I add the `|` it is not working. It is setting everything as missing. When I've tried different configurations including `case_when` it is still not working.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what could be causing your problems. See the example below. Everything works great here.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1111)
n=500
df = tibble(
  OCPIP = sample(0:40, n, replace = TRUE),
  GRPIP = sample(0:40, n, replace = TRUE),
) %>% mutate(cost_burdened = if_else(OCPIP == 0 | GRPIP == 0, NA_character_,
                                     if_else(OCPIP < 31 | GRPIP < 31, "No", "Yes")))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 500 x 3
   OCPIP GRPIP cost_burdened
   <int> <int> <chr>        
 1    25    27 No           
 2    35     3 No           
 3     5    18 No           
 4    37    32 Yes          
 5    25    39 No           
 6    30    11 No           
 7    38    27 No           
 8     0     1 NA           
 9    12    19 No           
10    23    16 No           
# ... with 490 more rows
```

Comment: This did not work for me with my data. I followed your mutate code example and it resulted in all NAs in the new variable

Comment: Did you execute all the code in my example exactly? Place your data using the `dput` function. Show me what results you get after running my code. Do all of this by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `case_when()` implementation:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.set(191)

cost_burdened <- tibble(
  OCPIP = c(0, 12, 31, 35, 47),
  
  GRPIP = c(31, 32, 15, 0, 47)
)

cost_burdened %>% 
  mutate(cost_burdened = case_when( 
    (OCPIP == 0) | (GRPIP == 0) ~ NA_character_, 
    (OCPIP < 31) | (GRPIP < 31) ~ "No", 
    TRUE ~ "Yes")
        )
```

Comment: This also did not work for me in my data. I get all NAs in the final coded variable.